# A string is required here (If Else Statement) in Crystal 2008

Tags: if-statement, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Hi I am getting an error

> 'A string is required here'

when trying the following in Crystal 2008:

```
If {InvPrice.SellingPrice} = 0 then "0" else 

({InvPrice.SellingPrice}-ccur({?Pm-Documents/Document/Det
```

Can someone please give me a clue on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by removing the double quotes:

```
If {InvPrice.SellingPrice} = 0 then 0 else 

({InvPrice.SellingPrice}-ccur({?Pm-Documents/Document/Det
```